# The attached image is not shown in jupyter notbook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, attachment

Attached image is not showing only in my jupyter notebook. It just shows the text "image.png". When I share the same file with other people, nothing goes wrong and the image does not appear only in my jupyter notebook. Is it a version issue? I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

```
![image.png](attachment:9c4294b5-debe-4fd2-a313-73adeeaf789b.png)
```

Comment: Which tool are you using to edit and run your notebook?

Comment: try this
![image.png](9c4294b5-debe-4fd2-a313-73adeeaf789b.png)
just remove attachment:

Comment: working! But I'm still wondering why the old way of using "attachment" works in someone else's jupyter but not mys.